# Firefox Crashing

Tags: 14.04, firefox, lts

Since I upgraded to 14.04 LTS my Firefox crashes every few minutes.  I asked this question before and there has been not response. I can not get into my Yahoo account.  What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Is there anything interesting in `~/.mozilla/firefox/Crash Reports`

Comment: As a temporary work-around you can install `chromium` to check e-mail and such.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04.01. I have read some of the issues that Mozilla automatically traced and they mentioned "ubuntu webaccounts".

I let the report be propagated to Mozilla issue tracking system and, as a precaution, I removed Ubuntu Webaccounts plugin, using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove xul-ext-webaccounts
```

Currently, my Firefox and Ubuntu installation, in that matter, seems stabilized.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue using Ubuntu 14.04. My system will freeze. My mouse moves, but nothing else is responsive. Cant even bring up a terminal with cntr + alt + F2. At this point I must either power down my system or hold down alt + SysRq and then type the letters R E I S U B.

Because of this issue I have downloaded and installed google chrome. I haven't had any issues with the crashes since. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and many posted that it was a flash problem. The problem persisted through Firefox and I switched to Chromium, but it still continued. I started Chromium-Browser via the terminal and watched the errors I was getting. I searched some of these and people were saying the problems associated with those specific errors had to do with the Ubuntu theme that was running. This seemed completely crazy to me, but nonetheless I switched the theme to 'Industrial' under Preferences, Customize Look and Feel and voila!

My browser has been open and running for days now finally. Prior to doing this my browsers would crash every 3-5 minutes and sometimes immediately upon trying to open (which makes searching for help miserable). It makes no sense to me how the theme of an OS could have any impact on a browser but I tried everything else suggested and nothing worked, but this is what fixed mine.