# Touchpad broken, firefox crashes, no space in /boot and antivirus

Tags: firefox, mouse

I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 for several days on a Toshiba satellite 600 series. It was designed for windows 7.

It might be a little bit damaged by a lightning strike in May 2015.

The issue is that the touchpad doesn't move the cursor - and also that Firefox web browser closes on it's own

Today I wanted to run an update but the computer told me that there is not enough space on the partition an to run `sudo apt-get clean`, but I don't know how to use this command.

I'm wondering if the computer has a virus - is there any antivirus system for Ubuntu?

Finally, I installed with encryption - can I remove that?

Comment: also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Touchpad

This [Touchpad stopped working out of the blue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367701/touchpad-stopped-working-out-of-the-blue), [Ubuntu 12.04 - touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264555/ubuntu-12-04-touchpad-not-working), 
[Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working) and [a quick Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=touchpad%20doesn%27t%20work%20ubuntu) may help you.

---

#### Firefox

For Firefox check out [Firefox keeps crashing on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575769/firefox-keeps-crashing-on-ubuntu-14-04), [Firefox Crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511901/firefox-crashing) and [Firefox 39 crashing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/646795/firefox-39-crashing); and again, [Google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=touchpad%20doesn%27t%20work%20ubuntu).

---

#### Update issues

[How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) and also [What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition)

---

#### Antivirus

There is antivirus - but do you really need it? Probably not [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10373/do-i-need-to-have-antivirus-software-installed) If you do go for one, [ClamXAV](https://www.clamxav.com/) and [ClamTK](http://clamtk.sourceforge.net/) are the usual choices.

---

> Next time you ask, we need more information (e.g. does Firefox give any errors in terminal, what makes you think you have a virus, and provide the exact output of terminal errors for the /boot issue.
>
> It's also better to ask each question separately so that we can answer each one individually - making it easier to search and also to mark as duplicate, so we get you the answer sooner.